# Arreglos: presentar numeros pares

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Arreglo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);

        int[] arr = new int [7];
        int i;

        for (i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i ++){
        System.out.printf(" Ingrese numero [%d]: ", i);
        arr[i] = teclado.nextInt();
        }

        for (i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i ++){
            if (arr[i] % 2 == 0){
                System.out.printf(" Los numeros pares son [% d] ", i);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Necesito imprimir los elementos del arreglo que son pares. Por favor si me indican donde esta el error o si es necesario añadir algo mas ... Gracias

Comment: Si lo que quieres es imprimir el numero, en el  `System.out.print` tienes que poner `arr[i]` ya que si solo pone `i` te imprimira la posicion, no el numero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo unico que debes de cambiar en tu codigo es lo siguiente:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Arreglo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);

        int[] arr = new int [7];
        int i;

        for (i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i ++){
        System.out.printf(" Ingrese numero [%d]: ", i);
        arr[i] = teclado.nextInt();
        }

        for (i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i ++){
            if (arr[i] % 2 == 0){
                System.out.printf(" Los numeros pares son [%d] ", arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Esta enviando `i` el cual corresponde al indice, por lo tanto te imprime los recorridos del ciclo que cumplen con el `if` debes de cambia `System.out.printf(" Los numeros pares son [%d] ", arr[i]);`